# How do you get 35400 out of 35418.8?

Tags: java

I'm doing the following:

```
SELECT round(35418.8, -2) FROM compa_8039
```

the result is: 35400

In java I have to get the same result, but I can't.

How do you do this in java, for a value equals 35418.8 ??

Comment: "In java I have get the same, but I can't" - ?

Comment: urmm. just assume that OP is not really good in english

Comment: Improve your question by editing and add a bit more details. What have you tried and where you are facing problem

Comment: @fge operations on `double` (or `float`) and `int` will result in the floating point type used. Change `n` to `(int) n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same thing can be achieved using the `BigDecimal` class and its [`setScale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) method:

```
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(35418.8);
bd = bd.setScale(-2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
int result = bd.intValue();

System.out.println(result);
```

This will print the value:

```
35400
```

Comment: @julioizquierdo Glad it helped. If you want to accept one of the two answers, then click the checkmark under the vote counter of that answer. But keep in mind, that you can only accept 1 answer.

Comment: I don't understand... I have to check ?.. Where I see it ?

Comment: On the left side of each answer is a big number (`0` at my answer, `1` as Vorsprungs answer). Under it is a checkmark. You can click it to accept that answer as correct. But you can only accept one answer, so you have to decide which one is better. You can also read [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ROUND(X), ROUND(X,D)
>
> Rounds the argument X to D decimal places. The rounding algorithm depends on the data type > of X. D defaults to 0 if not specified. D can be negative to cause D digits left of the 
>   decimal point of the value X to become zero.

see

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

so 35418.8 with two places to the left of the decimal point is 35400

edit:

Sorry to do this in java

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
       Double x=35418.18;
        int representation=(x.intValue()/100)*100;
        System.out.println(representation);
     }
}
```

Comment: He wants the same functionality in Java.

Comment: @Tom thanks, yeah should read the whole question.   Complete answer now